# SequenceEqual different results

Tags: c#, iequatable

in the code below calling `SequenceEqual` on generic list return true (as expected) when List is defined with class generic type (`EquatableClass.Equals<>` is called).

If list is defined with `IEquatable` interface, Equals method is not called and result is false (object.Equals is called instead, not in code).

The question is, why the `EquatableClass.Equals<>` method is not called in the second case?

```
public class EquatableClass : IEquatable<EquatableClass>
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Equals(EquatableClass other) => this.Name.Equals(other.Name);        
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var A = new List<EquatableClass> {  new EquatableClass { Name = "A" } };
    var B = new List<EquatableClass> {  new EquatableClass { Name = "A" } };

    var result1 = A.SequenceEqual(B); // == true;

    var AA = new List<IEquatable<EquatableClass>> {  new EquatableClass { Name = "A" } };
    var BB = new List<IEquatable<EquatableClass>> {  new EquatableClass { Name = "A" } };

    var result2 = AA.SequenceEqual(BB); // == false;    
}
```

Comment: Because the parameters don't match the class parameters.  So the default method is used.

Comment: This is the reason that if you are implementing `IEquatable<T>` you should override the behavior of `Equals(object)` too to match the behavior.

Comment: Always also override `Equals`(+ `GetHashCode`), f.e.: `public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                EquatableClass other = obj as EquatableClass;
                return obj != null && other.Equals(this);
            }`

Answer (score 1):

The `SequenceEqual<T>` method will try to see if it can convert `T` to `IEquatable<T>`, and if it can, it will use `IEquatable<T>.Equals` for equality.

When you have a `List<EquatableClass>` it will then try to convert `EquatableClass` to `IEquatable<EquatableClass>`, and that succeeds, so it uses the appropriate `Equals` method.

When you have a `List<IEquatable<EquatableClass>>` it will then try to convert `IEquatable<EquatableClass>` to `IEquatable<IEquatable<EquatableClass>>`, and that will fail, because the actual object doesn't implement `IEquatable<IEquatable<EquatableClass>>`, so it resorts to the default behavior of using `object.Equals(object)`, which you don't override.

Comment: Ok, as I understand, it can be reduced to: `typeof(IEquatable<IEquatable<EquatableClass>>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(EquatableClass)) == false` and the reason is because IEquatable interface generic parameter is declared as invariant, am I correct?

Comment: @user4662448 It wouldn't be any different if `IEquatable` were covariant or contravariant.  That conversion wouldn't be applicable in any of those situations for that type.  It would need to actually implement `IEquatable<IEquatable<EquatableClass>>` and add the extra `Equals` method for that to work.  (And that's clearly not a good idea).

Comment: But adding extra `Equals` don't work, object.Equals is called instead...

Comment: @user4662448 If you add a second `IEquatable` implementation it would be used.  You don't want to do that.  The bug is that you're typing the list as `IEquatable` when you shouldn't be. The correct solution is to use a list of the types you actually have the ability to compare, which is an `EquatableClass` not an `IEquatable<EquatableClass>>`, but if you add the additional `IEquatable` implementation you'd at least see what's going on, although you shouldn't keep it in your code.

Comment: Servy, you wrote about additional `IEquatable<IEquatable<EquatableClass>>` implementation, right? But when I add the implementation into the `EquatableClass` the `Equals(IEquatable<EquatableClass> other)` method is not called.. why? (my personal opinion is that it is somehow related with invariancy of IEquatable ... but I might be wrong).

Comment: @user4662448 No, like I said, the variance of the interface isn't relevant here.  Without seeing what you'd written, I couldn't say why it's not behaving as you expect.  It's a tangent off of your question anyway though, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for answers.